# Android: Detect if user is on a bus/train/tram/etc

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

I know this is a very open question, but does anyone know how I can determine if a user is on public transport? Ideally, I'd have a background service running such that only subscribers who are on public transport receive my alerts.

Comment: How could something possibly determine that?

Comment: Perhaps a fusion of maps data and sensors? A classifier?

Comment: What user would like you to detect where you are specifically?

Comment: I agree. Most consumers are stupid. If they don't like it, then they shouldn't have bought an Android. And if they do have such a device, they should understand that they give consent by accepting permissions. Personally, I don't have a smart phone.

Comment: It seems like you're asking to know if someone is in his bedroom or in his kitchen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can determine if a user is on public transport?

You ask the user, "Yo! You on public transport?"

> Perhaps a fusion of maps data and sensors?

You can use [the activity recognition portion of the Google Play Services location API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) to determine if the user is in a moving vehicle.

However, there is no requirement for governments to collect, let alone publish, the GPS coordinates of all public transportation vehicles. Hence, there is no way for you to determine the location of all the world's buses, trains, trams, etc. And, as a result, you have no way to determine if the user is on one of those.

Comment: Hi, thanks to you I found http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html

Comment: [What an odd set of constants.](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html) Love to hear how well the detection works. I ride pretty fast, and drive pretty slow.

Comment: These flags, in conjunction with viewing the WiFi SSIDs (even the buses have WiFi where I live) should give me what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Every method of transportation has it's own move-characreristics. E.g. a train takes long time to speed up and down. A bus takes little shorter and stops more often. Analyzing these accelaration-characferistics should give a hint on the form of transportation.

Next, you could analyze the routes using map Information, if you can get it somewhere. May be you van gather it yourself: record a route, let user tell whether he/she is on train, bus, walking. Save this Information for later use, also for other travellers.

Lot's of possibilities. All are rather difficult.